# Is NdisGetCurrentSystemTime different from KeQuerySystemTime?

Tags: windows, time, kernel, drivers, ndis

I found that MinGW Win32 compatibility layer has following definition in ndis.h:

```
#define NdisGetCurrentSystemTime KeQuerySystemTime
```

In WinDDK, definition is:

```
EXPORT VOID NdisGetCurrentSystemTime(PLARGE_INTEGER pSystemTime);
```

Does native NdisXX function really isn't adding anything to KeQuerySystemTime call? Or there is a large difference (allowed IRQL etc) between them in native OS rather than in MinGW hacked point of view? Do they relate differently to the resolution of system timer (which can be retrieved via `KeQueryPerformanceCounter()`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An experiment had shown that two times (NdisGetCurrentSystemTime and KeQuerySystemTime) are identical, however I still want some proofs that Ndis* version carries some specifics.

A link to remember (#1): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wdk/thread/75c08500-e788-49c1-ac5f-9beb8101bdde

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what WDK version was used in the original question but in the current WDK version (10.xx) the definition is `#define NdisGetCurrentSystemTime KeQuerySystemTime`.